# android Icon dont fill whole spot

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using visual studio Xamarin.
My icons are centerd in a squre like shape like this:

[image]

I want my picture to fill the spot and be like:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: code please.. xml

Comment: [Activity(Label = "name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IValueEventListener
    {

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official document: [Launcher Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size).

If you don't want padding around the image of your icon, make sure your picture has the right size.

[image]

In Android 7.1 (API level 25) and earlier, launcher icons were sized at 48 x 48 dp.

For other size of icons, you should be able to structure your resource directory like this:

[image]